# Allow only left aligned zeros using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am fairly new to using regex. I have a serial number which can take the following forms: VV-XXXXXX-P or VVXXXXXXP
If the hyphen variant is used, then the number of 'X' can be variable. For example 01-162-8 is equivalent to 010001628.

In order to identify the 2 formats, I have created the following regex's:

```
String HYPHENS = ([0]{1}[13]{1}-[1-9]{1,6}-[0-9]{1})
String NO_HYPHENS = ([0]{1}[13]{1}[0-9]{6}[0-9]{1})
```

However the issue with the NO_HYPHENS variant is that it allows 0 anywhere in the sequence
For example: 010010628 should not be a valid sequence because there's a non leading 0.

Additionally, how would I create a regex that I can use to replace all 0 from the sequence but the first one? I have tried the following but it also replaces the first 0.

```
String code = 010001234;
code = code.replaceAll("0+", "");
```

How could I modify the regex's to achieve this?

Comment: `[0-9]` matches zeros. Use `[1-9]` to match non-zeros only

Comment: Not possible since when using the non-hyphen option there MIGHT be leading zeros in the XXXXX part

Comment: Ah, use `String NO_HYPHENS = "0[13](?!0*[1-9]0)[0-9]{6}[0-9]"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DD5KE5/1).

Comment: Does it work? Also, to remove zeros not at the start, use `(?!^)0`

Comment: Yes, it seems to work alright!
Thank you for your answer and time & have a nice week-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
String NO_HYPHENS = "0[13](?!0*[1-9]0)[0-9]{6}[0-9]";
code = code.replaceAll("(?!^)0(?!$)", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DD5KE5/1).
The `0[13](?!0*[1-9]0)[0-9]{6}[0-9]` regex matches:

- `0` - zero
- `[13]` - one or three
- `(?!0*[1-9]0)` - any zeros followed with a non-zero digit and then a zero is not allowed at this location
- `[0-9]{6}`  - six digits
- `[0-9]` - a digit.

I understand you use it in Java with `.matches`, else, add `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

Also, the `(?!^)0(?!$)` regex will match any zero that is not at the string start/end position.

Comment: As @mateuszl1995 pointed out, this will also remove a 0 on the last position

Comment: @Bogdan If you need to not remove the final `0`, use `(?!^)0(?!$)`

Answer (score 1):

```
^0[13]0*[1-9]*[0-9]$
```

`^` - beginning of string
`0` - first sign must be zero
`[13]` - second sign must be one or three
`0*` - sequence of zeros of variable length
`[1-9]` - sequence of non-zeros of variable length
`[0-9]` - finally one digit (it can be replaced with \d also)
`$` - end of string

This regex has one problem: it doesn't check how many digits are in the XXXXXX section of serial number. But you can check it with length function:

```
      String code = "010000230";
      if (code.matches("^0[13]0*[1-9]*[0-9]$") && code.length() == 9) {
         // code is valid
      }
      // replacement
      code = code.replaceAll("^(0[13])0*([1-9]*[0-9])$", "$1$2");
```

Explanation of the replacement:
`(0[13])` group number 1 (groups are in bracket)
`0*` some zeros
`([1-9]*[0-9])` group number 2

This will be replaced with:
`$1$2` group number 1 and group number 2 ($1 means group number 1)

Comment: While I appreciate your time, I will accept the above answer since it fits better to my particular problem as it doesn't require a length check

Comment: Warning: accepted answer also deletes zero if it is on last position
010000230 will be replaced with 0123